# jQuery search page for text and change it, but don't if it's already there

Tags: jquery, html, replace

OK, a slightly confusing question - apologies. But I have the following links on my site www.kateguestdesigns.com AND www.kateguestdesigns.com/home

Using jQuery I want to change all instances of www.kateguestdesigns.com to www.kateguestdesigns.com/home. I'm currently using this code:

```
 $('body').html( $('body').html().replace(/kateguestdesigns.com/gi,'kateguestdesigns.com/home') );
```

Which searches for 'kateguestdesigns.com' and changes it to 'kateguestdesigns.com/home. The issue I have is that it also change kateguestdesigns.com/home to kateguestdesigns.com/home/home.

Is there a way for me to get around this by only applying the change to kateguestdesigns.com?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the end of string anchor. Try this instead:

```
$('body').html( $('body').html().replace(/kateguestdesigns.com$/gi,'kateguestdesigns.com/home') );
```

The `$` tells replace to match a string that ends immediately after the `.com`. Note that this will not match `/kateguestdesigns.com/` to account for the trailing slash, simply escape and add it before the `$`:

```
$('body').html().replace(/kateguestdesigns.com\/$/gi,'kateguestdesigns.com/home') );
```

For a reference on regex special characters see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/kateguestdesigns.com$/gi,'kateguestdesigns.com/home'));
```

Added the `$` to the Regex to indicate the end of the string.